# Computer randomly shuts off and restarts with Reason Code: 0x500ff

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot, events

My buddy's computer keeps randomly restarting. Usually when he's playing a game. It has randomly restarted just when he's on YouTube. 
Event Viewer says:

> The process C:\Windows\system32\winlogon.exe (SPENCER-DESKTOP)
>   has initiated the power off of computer SPENCER-DESKTOP
>   on behalf of user NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>   for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
>   Reason Code: 0x500ff
>   Shutdown Type: power off
>   Comment:
>
> **param1**  C:\Windows\system32\winlogon.exe (SPENCER-DESKTOP)
>   **param2**  SPENCER-DESKTOP
>   **param3**  No title for this reason could be found
>   **param4**  0x500ff
>   **param5**  power off
>   **param6**
>   **param7**  NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

[Here is a screenshot of Event Viewer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhIjI.png) 
I think this event was it.  He has a prebuilt cyberpower gaming PC. 
Any suggestions are good.

Comment: Take a look at this MS Community [page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-shutting-down/6f0de1eb-5360-4f1e-b183-3832f1b92cee)

Answer (score 6):

The KB article for this says that this may be a **secondary Event Viewer entry** while the real reason should be logged somewhere next to it (within seconds), with the same Event ID 1074:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2001061/on-a-computer-running-windows-vista-windows-7-windows-server-2008-and

The second entry, if you can find it, should have the real reason listed. For me, the second entry would be **"The process Explorer.EXE has initiated the power off of computer..."** to indicate that I used the desktop or start menu to ask for a shut down.

In your friend's case this may also be a short on the *power button*, or even a *misbehaving program*. In an extreme case, CPU *overheating* might be the issue, etc.

My custom-built system used to restart reliably on its own when I *overclocked* it a bit too much, for example. Windows 10 Pro here.

Good luck!

Comment: I have lots of shutdowns in my log that are 0x500ff, but with no accompanying event that I'm able to find.

Comment: In my case there was an accompanying event id 109, Kernel-Power, indicating "The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition. Shutdown Reason : Kernel API". Tracked this down and it correlates to a user pushing the case power button rather than using the start button.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, after sorting the events by 'Date and Time' I noticed an Info level event from Kernel-Power about 10 seconds earlier.

[image: Event Viewer Critical Battery Trigger Met]

Normally I would filter for just Error and Warning, but the Info event provided a clue: **Critical Battery Trigger Met**.

This seemed odd since the laptop was plugged in, but examining the Power Options > Advanced Settings gave an explanation.

The Critical battery action was set to Hibernate for **both** On Battery and Plugged in.  My laptop had been unplugged over the weekend and the battery drained below 5%.  Once it recharged back up to 5%, I believe the action triggered and it attempted to hibernate.  I've switched my High Performance and Balanced profiles from `Hibernate` to `Do nothing` while Plugged in.
[image: Power Options, Corrected]