# Random restarts (0x500ff)

Tags: windows-10

Dell G7 7590 laptop, win10 edu.

I get random restarts, with the event:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        User32
Date:          7/9/21 7:45:18 PM
Event ID:      1074
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      lap
Description:
The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe (LAP) has initiated the restart of computer LAP on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x500ff
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="User32" Guid="{b0aa8734-56f7-41cc-b2f4-de228e98b946}" EventSourceName="User32" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1074</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-09-07T07:45:18.2371530Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2071</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="832" ThreadID="3624" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>LAP</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe (lap)</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">LAP</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">No title for this reason could be found</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">0x500ff</Data>
    <Data Name="param5">restart</Data>
    <Data Name="param6">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="param7">NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

There are no other events around that time that may link to it.
The CPU isn't overheating, and no battery issues.

I'm not clear why an OS has the functionality to restart at all without user intervention. Also, if there's a problem, give me a freeze or a blue screen; don't just restart (the next level after forcing updates on the customer).

I tried the following to disable unauthorized restart, but nothing worked:

[Computer randomly shuts off and restarts with Reason Code: 0x500ff](https://superuser.com/questions/1417097/computer-randomly-shuts-off-and-restarts-with-reason-code-0x500ff)

https://www.itechtics.com/disable-automatic-restart/

https://support.hp.com/ph-en/document/c01853741

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/incorrect-shutdown-reason-code-sel

---

To clarify, I'm not looking for the usual routine to diagnose my system and try to fish for something. I want to disable unauthorized restarts. If there's a problem or a dire need, then report or crash.

---

> If you manually temporarily disable all applications that are
> automatically started with AutoRuns, does the behavior still happen,
> how often does this event happen. Is there any pattern to this
> behavior?

The problem started 4 days ago.
It started by restarting 5 times in two hours. Then, every few hours. Once, it almost hasn't restarted for a whole day, and then it restarted twice in 3 min.

I don't see any pattern or anything related to it.

Since it's random, I can't just start the computer without apps or in safe mode and just way for something to happen. And again, I'm not interested in fishing for a non-existent problem that might cause a restart, which the OS won't tell me about. There's no justification at all for a restart without user prompt, it's a serious bug, and I'm looking for a patch to prevent such things.
If someone was able to write an app that disables the cursed auto update, then maybe there's a saint who wrote something for this too.

---

It has just rebooted again 5 times in a row (1min apart).

---

It appears that the reason is (kind of) given, but they were just lazy writing it. These are the reason codes:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-reason-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Of course, they won't provide everything in one place, so the other part is in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\reason.h
```

The reason code 0x500ff is in fact 0x 000 500 ff, which is a 3-part code:

1. Flags such as SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_USER_DEFINED and SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED. In my case, none.
2. Major reason. In my case: SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_SYSTEM, System failure.
   (I dismissed what @user1292580 said, but he was right after all.)
3. Minor reason. In my case: SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_NONE.

So, the restart was a kind of an uninformative blue screen due to system failure with no logs or crash dumps.

Not sure if it makes me feel better. Maybe. There's an unexplained system error, which needs to be tracked down.

---

My duplicate post:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/random-restarts-0x500ff/12ccb286-4411-42ff-ab52-33b3d5faf986?auth=1

Comment: Try the suggestions in this Microsoft article:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/incorrect-shutdown-reason-code-sel

Comment: It means System Error without any more specific info. `SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_SYSTEM 0x00050000  System failure.`

Comment: @John, tried, didn't help.

Comment: If you manually temporarily disable all applications that are automatically started with AutoRuns, does the behavior still happen, how often does this event happen.  Is there any pattern to this behavior?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: I answered your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After methodically trying to track the problematic process using procmon (which ironically crashes, leaks, and exhausts system resources), completely by chance I found out that someone remotely exploited a vulnerability in remote desktop. Disabling it resolved the issue. For the full saga:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/random-restarts-0x500ff/12ccb286-4411-42ff-ab52-33b3d5faf986?auth=1

Comment: I really love how you didn't mention the real solution here and sent me to the Microsoft meme page which never yields any real result.

Comment: I mentioned the solution: disable the remote desktop. You are asking how? Google "disable remote desktop." The MS page is just a detailed story of how much effort I put into tracking the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest BIOS version.

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/g-series-15-7590-laptop/drivers

Comment: I've tried already.