# How to downgrade windows?

Tags: windows

I started having these issues, which make win10 completely unreliable and thus useless to me:

[Random restarts (0x500ff)](https://superuser.com/questions/1675530/random-restarts-0x500ff)

I'd like to downgrade. Which latest version of windows is reliable--doesn't do restart/sleep/shutdown/hibernate without user approval--and how do I downgrade to it (I don't have any recovery info) without reinstalling from scratch?

---

I've accepted @Gantendo's answer since he answered the question: it's not possible.

However, I don't agree with him that the OS is stable. Having said that, I'm looking online, and it seems that any OS, even linux, thinks that rebooting without a reason due to a panic is an acceptable solution (who knows, maybe the user won't notice that it made a blunder?).

Comment: Windows 10 is the most stable ever. Perhaps you're having hardware errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 is reliable. Windows 7 is no longer supported. It is only useful if you want to play certain old games.
Downgrading to an older Windows version is not a good solution to your problem.
Reinstall Windows 10 and see if that fixes your problem.

All versions of Windows are reliable, even Vista. No versions of Windows restart/sleep/shutdown/hibernate without user approval (if you configure and use them correctly).

You cannot downgrade to an older version of Windows without installing it from scratch unless you have a Windows.old folder  https://www.thewindowsclub.com/go-back-to-an-earlier-build-of-windows-10

Update the BIOS to the latest version. https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/g-series-15-7590-laptop/drivers

Comment: There are a lot of systems in specific and closed applications (off line/local) without versions for Windows 10, so it's difficult to swallow: *It is only useful if you want to play certain old games*