# Remote desktop works from linux but not from win10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

The server is a win10.

The login fails (bad user/pass) when using the win10 rdp client.

The login succeeds when using rdesktop from WSL ubuntu.

Could it be that the win10 rdp client isn't compatible with the win10 rdp server, which only a linux rdp client is compatible with?

---

Maybe I should mention that I'm using an ssh tunnel. Maybe rdp connecting to localhost confuses it in terms of credentials? It shouldn't.

I leave it as another win10 bug. RDP isn't so good anyway, and it has vulnerability (although, I don't intend to use it to access my computer):

[Random restarts (0x500ff)](https://superuser.com/questions/1675530/random-restarts-0x500ff)

NoMachine is better anyway.

But I'm still curios about this.

---

Duplicate:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/remote-desktop-works-from-linux-but-not-from-win10/8c1ba6e1-898f-4c6b-a3e9-6e6cfe0ba7c6

Comment: Windows 10 RDP to WIndows Server, Windows Workstation works fine. I use it. Delete your RDP profile, restart and then try again.

Comment: I was kidding, of course, rdp from win10 to win10 is supposed to work. And I tried restart or a new profile. Could there be some credentials that win10 adds for the remote (complicated domain) user (maybe it needs to be defined locally or something?) and ubuntu doesn't that conflict with something?

Comment: That seems strange. If a new RDP profile did not work, and if the remote machine is on a domain, you may need to add the domain to the user name . But I would think Linux would have to do the same. There may be something wrong with the Windows 10 machine trying to access.